# Hibernate When Entity Change, Database Changes Immediately

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a function which reads all data from my database, make some changes and return a list of data. But when I make changes in entity's field, all related data changes too. Code will explain better.

```
List<ICmsExemptRestrictDet> models = DAOLocator.getCmsExemptRestrictDetDAO().findByDefinitionId(definitionId);

for(ICmsExemptRestrictDet model : models){
        if(CmsExemptionParameterConstants.ParameterTypeOfDetail.EXPONENTIAL_CODE.toString().equals(model.getParameterType())){
            String exponentialCode = model.getParameterValue();
            String exponentialName = //some data
            model.setParameterValue(exponentialName.concat(" : ").concat(exponentialCode));
        }
}
```

At the beginning, database has 3 data such as

- 0100
- 0200
- 0300

When my code runs, they becomes

- BlaBla : 0100
- BlaBla2 : 0200
- HelloWorld : 0300

Neither I trigger update method of my repository nor insert. I dont know how it effect my database.

Thanks

Comment: That is the nature of a managed entity. Hibernate detects changes and when in an active transaction/session it will automatically syncronize changes with the database.